# Utility function to convert everything to optional

Tags: flowtype

Many times I find myself passing in as an arg a certain `Shape` type but where each key is optional, only at least one is required.

For example:

```
type Shape = {
    +isFetching: boolean,
    +errorFetching: null | string
}

type ShapeOpt = {
    isFetching?: boolean,
    errorFetching?: boolean
}


function set(data: ShapeOpt) {
    for (const key in data) {
        global[key] = data[key];
    }
}
```

Is there a utility function to convert from `Shape` to `ShapeOpt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `$Shape<Type>` helper for generating an object type where each key is optional. But I don't know of a way to say that at least one item is required automatically.

Comment: Thank you sir so much, you have answered three of my questions so quickly! Sincerest thanks! That's ok about the at least one is required, thanks!